# Refactor LINQ ForEach to return IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I am creating an array with the following `CreateArray` static method:

```
public static int[] CreateArray(int size)
{
    var ret = new int[size];
    ret[0] = 0;
    ret[1] = 1;

    Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(2, size - 2), i =>
    {
        ret[i] = Func(i).Count();
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Where Func looks like:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Func(int i)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to refactor the `CreateArray` method in something like:

```
public static int[] CreateArray(int size)
{
    var tableFromIndex2 = ...
    return new[] { 0, 1 }
        .Concat(tableFromIndex2)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PLINQ could be useful here:

```
var tableFromIndex = ParallelEnumerable.Range(2, size - 2)
        .AsOrdered()
        .Select(i => Func(i).Count());

return new[] { 0, 1 }
        .Concat(tableFromIndex)
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey svick, I thought it was right but actually I got the results not ordered by `i`. I mean, I am OK to run the `Func(i).Count()` in parallel but then the result should be placed in the `i` position...

Comment: Thanks svick, I din't know `AsOrdered()` exist